# GDB "Target request failed:"

Tags: c, gdb, openocd

Target request failed: Don't know how to run. Try "help target".
I am running eclipse on ubuntu,
I configured eclipse to debug with openocd.
c project on Eclipse
I tried to run eclipse as root permissions.

"help target" command output is here

---

```
(gdb) help target:
List of target subcommands:
target child -- Unix child process (started by the "run" command)
target core -- Use a core file as a target
target exec -- Use an executable file as a target
target extended-remote -- Use a remote computer via a serial line
target record -- Log program while executing and replay execution from log
target record-btrace -- Collect control-flow trace and provide the execution history
target record-core -- Log program while executing and replay execution from log
target record-full -- Log program while executing and replay execution from log
target remote -- Use a remote computer via a serial line
target tfile -- Use a trace file as a target
Type "help target" followed by target subcommand name for full documentation.
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Command name abbreviations are allowed if unambiguous.
```

---

Comment: Check if the gdb command is being run correctly. Maybe gdb cannot find the correct target. Hard to say since I do not know your eclipse setup.

Comment: Are you using correct gdb version? Did you install "gdb hardware debugging" plug-in? (could be useful: http://hertaville.com/2012/09/16/part-3-debugging-openocd-0-6-0/)